# Android Car Head unit: external microphone works for some apps, but not in calls or Google voice search

Tags: android, audio

I installed a cheap chinese Android based car head unit in my 15 year old second hand car, with probably Android 8 or 9 (maybe even a fake version where the version shown is higher than is installed).  For most things it works.  Sound output is good, bluetooth works, Wifi works, Google apps like Maps, Chrome, Youtube all work.

I have an external mic attached to it.  There is a sound recording app, which records the sound when I use this mic.  I can replay the sounds, so far so good.  So here's the thing: the phone app does not pick up this mic, and also no sound on the tiny mic that's built in.  Same for Google Voice Search, it just doesn't pick up anything.  When I call someone, they don't hear me speaking at all.

My question is: how do I go about debugging it?  Is there some kind of app that I can use to diagnose, which will at least show device mapping, or show signals like in Windows?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn why you will most likely not receive a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Your question probably belongs to the "Android Enthusiasts" Stackexchange.

Comment: Did you find a way to make the phone app use use the mic? Having the same issue: on sound recording, the records are loud and clear, on phone calls, people on the other end of the call barely hear a thing.